# Handling thread on incoming call

Tags: android, multithreading

Currently my application fetches data from server inside a dialog box and a thread.
What should be done when an incoming call occurs.
Right now I'm doing this. I want to know if this methos is right or something else has to done.

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Utility.debugger("PAUSE 1");
    if (ScreenReceiver.wasScreenOn) {  

                    // this is the case when onPause() is called by the system due to a screen state change  
                    Utility.killDialog();

                    System.out.println("SCREEN TURNED OFF");  

                } else {  

                    Utility.debugger("PAUSE 2");

                 // this is when onPause() is called when the screen state has not changed  
     }  

    super.onPause();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Utility.debugger("PAUSE 3");
    if (!ScreenReceiver.wasScreenOn) {  

               // this is when onResume() is called due to a screen state change  

                     System.out.println("SCREEN TURNED ON"); 

                     Utility.debugger("PAUSE 4");
                        Utility.resumeDialog(); 

                } else {  

                     // this is when onResume() is called when the screen state has not changed



            } 

    super.onResume();


}


public static void killDialog()
{
    if(dialog != null || dialog.isShowing() )
    {dialog.dismiss();
        t.interrupt();
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void resumeDialog()
{
    if(dialog != null  )
    {
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.show();
        t.run();

    }
}
```

Where t is thread and dialog is progressDialog.
I hv also cheched on pause and resume is the device goes into sleep.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're really trying to do is create a dialog box for the user.  There is ample documentation for that here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Here's a simple example:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
progressDialog.show()
```

When you want to stop the dialog, call

```
progressDialog.cancel()
```

---

If you are curious about threading on Android, I'd suggest taking a look at AsyncTask.  This class (combined with Activity.runOnUiThread()) should handle 99% of threading issues on Android.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I want to stop both dialog and the running thread when incoming call comes And restart when the call ends as it returns ro the application.

Comment: @user983364  Threads cannot be paused.  And interrupting them is usually a bad idea.  It is common, however, to use a flag to simulate this type of behavior.  eg  `if (isPaused) Thread.sleep(100)`

Comment: @user983364 Another possibility for effecting a pause on a thread is to block the thread using notify/wait or some other locking mechanism.  Though an `isPaused` flag will keep your code a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Thread use Asynck Task which will same as Thread in android. There are four methods 
1. onPreExecute()
2. doInBackground(String... arg0)
3. onProgressUpdate(String...values)
4. onPostExecute(Void result)

First start progress bar inside the onPreExecute() then Downloading code comes under doInBackground() and then after all this dismiss progress bar inside the onPostExecute method.

Comment: will this handle incoming call or something has to be done to dismiss dialog and stop Asyn task on incoming call.

Comment: Yes It can handle incoming call also. all you have to is that inside the doInBackground(String... arg0)  background call the publishProgress("finish"); it is inbuilt method which will call the onProgressUpdate(String... values) inside that check the value if it is finish then dismiss your progress bar.      Please go through with below link: http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-async-task.html

Comment: Thanks! that will help me alot :)

Comment: I tried it but cant get aroung it. dat be helpful if u provied code.